# Rails Deployment: moving static files to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-s3

Someone [posted something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736365/automate-deployment-of-files-to-amazon-s3) but it didn't really solve the problem.

I want to move all my static files (images, javascript, css) to an Amazon S3 bucket when I deploy my app, as well as rewrite those paths in my app, is there a simple way to accomplish this? or am I in for a huge amount of work here?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Huh? Why wouldn't you want to serve your static content from a content delivery network with hugely powerful servers around the world... Why waste my server's bandwidth sending static content? My servers memory and bandwidth is best used serving user specific data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other question was mine :p

I ended up going with a rake task that I tied in with asset_packager and my "normal" heroku deployment process.

I would love something was much smarter and could do the heavy lifting for me though.

Answer (score 0):

I also left an answer at the other question, I'm was looking into the same issue and will give this gem https://github.com/railsjedi/jammit-s3 a try later today.

Hope it helps,
Jeroen

Comment: Just implemented it, have a look at the https://github.com/makalu/jammit-s3 fork. It will enable you to set cache-control headers for the assets as well, which will add turbomode to your website!